# Where is the source archive for my Websphere portal classes?

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I'm pretty new to Websphere application development and I'm missing the source attachment for all the classes in the `com.ibm.wps.*` packages in my IBM Rational Application Developer setup. For example the class `com.ibm.wps.engine.Command` from JAR `wp.engine.impl.jar` has no source attached.

Do I have to install another package with the sources or where can I find it?

Also, excuse the question if it is so trivial and stupid... :-}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM does not distribute the sources for these libraries.

Comment: Hm, is there a javadoc archive available then?

Comment: javadoc can be downloaded here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc.html#v615javadoc It only includes packages IBM considers public, though.