# what is jar file name in order to get specific class

Tags: java

I am struggling for getting one jar to import like `import com.ibm.wps.portlets.PortletUtils;`
Let me know  which jar file or package should  add in worksapce to get import?

Comment: are you sure that is the name? I searched for this class and didnt find anything

Comment: findjar.com/index.x?query=com.ibm.wps.pb.utils.portlet

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652667/where-is-the-source-archive-for-my-websphere-portal-classes/2750419#2750419) might help you

Comment: yeah sure..Actual requirement is following code should be in CLass File  HttpServletRequest req=PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(request);" in order to  PortletUtils some jar file need to install so i need that jar file name? help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your class to compile you need *com.ibm.wps.portlets.PortletUtils* in you buildpath.

At my local installation of WebSphere 8 + Eclipse + some IBM-Eclipse-Extension i did the following:

1. *Add* WebSphere as Server-Runtime in *Window* - *Preferences* - *Server* - _Runtime Environment:
2. Go to *Libraries* in *Java Build Path* of the Eclipse-Project
3. Click on *Add Library...* - *Server Runtime* - *WebSphere Application Server v8.0*
4. Switch to *Order and Export* and check *WebSphere Application Server v8.0*

Now WebSphere-Classes are found at compile-time.
At runtime the class will be provided by WebSphere.

**Side note:** I only found *com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portlet.PortletUtils* in *com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar*

Comment: thank you DaniEll..but i couldn't get this in my nstallation of WebSphere 8

Comment: DanilEll still i am not getting here i couldn't attach my screen shot could you please provide your email id to sent

Comment: DaniEll, I have reached still this Click on point 2 which you meantioned but nothing is there in upcoming window.